# return partial pg database entry as JSON in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, database, postgresql

I have a RoR app with postgresql as database

Currently, I have this code:

```
def return_mssg_as_json
    id = params[:id].to_i
    @message = Message.find(id)
    render json: @message
end
```

and it returns this JSON:

```
{"id":13,"created_at":"2017-10-27T19:03:52.196Z","updated_at":"2017-10-27T19:03:52.196Z","text":"ASDF"}
```

How can I make it return only `{"text":"ASDF"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here...

First, you don't need to do `to_i` here:

```
def return_mssg_as_json
  id = params[:id].to_i
  @message = Message.find(id)
  render json: @message
end
```

You can just do:

```
def return_mssg_as_json
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  render json: @message
end
```

Now, if there's *any* chance that you might receive an `id` that doesn't have a matching record, you might want to do something like:

```
def return_mssg_as_json
  begin
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    render json: @message
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render json: {errors: :not_found}, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

Otherwise, if your record doesn't exist, you'll have an unhandled critical error. Instead, however, you could do:

```
def return_mssg_as_json
  if @message = Message.find_by(id: params[:id])
    render json: @message
  else
    render json: {errors: :not_found}, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

Now, back to your main question, you could do (as in the accepted answer)

```
def return_mssg_as_json
  if @message = Message.find_by(id: params[:id])
    render json: { message: @message[:text] }
  else
    render json: {errors: :not_found}, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

Although, to save yourself three characters, it seems you could do:

```
def return_mssg_as_json
  if @message = Message.find_by(id: params[:id])
    render json: { message: @message.text }
  else
    render json: {errors: :not_found}, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

Which is a great answer! But, in the future, if you want to return multiple values from `@message` (for example), you could do something like (assuming `@message` responds to `foo` and `bar`):

```
def return_mssg_as_json
  if @message = Message.find_by(id: params[:id])
    render json: @message.attributes.with_indifferent_access.slice(:text, :foo, :bar)
  else
    render json: {errors: :not_found}, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

This bit:

```
@message.attributes
```

converts the record into a hash of its values. This bit:

```
.with_indifferent_access
```

allows you to select key-value pairs using symbols instead of strings. And this bit:

```
.slice(:text, :foo, :bar)
```

specifies which key-value pairs to return. So, this would return something along the lines of (in JSON format, naturally):

```
{text: 'blah', foo: 'blah', bar: 'blah'}
```

Now, in your example, you didn't want `text`, you wanted `message`. So, you could do:

```
def return_mssg_as_json
  if @message = Message.find_by(id: params[:id])
    attr = @message.attributes.with_indifferent_access
    render json: attr.slice(:foo, :bar).merge!(message: attr[:text])
  else
    render json: {errors: :not_found}, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

Which would return something along the lines of (in JSON format, naturally):

```
{message: 'blah', foo: 'blah', bar: 'blah'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the following:

`render json: { message: @message[:text] }`

Comment: But how to return it as json like{"text":"ASDF"}. Your solution returns just the message.

Comment: Yeah but if I test it with "string" it should returnit as json {"message" :"string"}. Your solution returns just string.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to achieve such behavior, check an example here https://richonrails.com/articles/getting-started-with-jbuilder

Comment: This is also a good solution but the previous comment does all the necessary without using extra gems.